# DistilBERT Model Did Not Return Loss

Tags: python, tensorflow, bert-language-model

I'm attempting to replicate the Text Classification shown here

> https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/tasks/sequence_classification

Using my own data set. This is what I have so far:

```
!pip install accelerate
!pip install evaluate
!pip install transformers

import evaluate
from datasets import load_dataset
from transformers import AutoTokenizer
from transformers import DataCollatorWithPadding
from transformers import AutoModelForSequenceClassification, TrainingArguments, Trainer

RawData = load_dataset("csv", data_files = {"train": "Dataset Train.csv", "test": "Dataset Test.csv"})

print(RawData)

Tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("distilbert-base-uncased")

def TokenizeData (Data) :
    return Tokenizer(Data["Title"], truncation=True)

TokenizedData = RawData.map(TokenizeData, batched = True)

DataCollator = DataCollatorWithPadding(tokenizer = Tokenizer)

accuracy = evaluate.load("accuracy")

IDToLabel = {0: "Human", 1: "AI"}
LabelToId = {"Human": 0, "AI": 1}

def ComputeMetrics (evel):
    Predictions, Labels = eval
    Predictions = np.argmax(Predictions, axis = 1)
    return accuracy.compute(predictions = Predictions, references = Labels)

Model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained (
    "distilbert-base-uncased", num_labels = 2, id2label = IDToLabel, label2id = LabelToId
)

Args = TrainingArguments (

    output_dir = "0",
    learning_rate = 2e-5,
    per_device_train_batch_size = 16,
    per_device_eval_batch_size = 16,
    num_train_epochs = 2,
    weight_decay = 0.01,
    evaluation_strategy = "epoch",
    save_strategy = "epoch",
    load_best_model_at_end = True,
    push_to_hub = False,

)

T= Trainer (

    model = Model,
    args = Args,
    train_dataset = TokenizedData["train"],
    eval_dataset = TokenizedData["test"],
    tokenizer = Tokenizer,
    data_collator = DataCollator,
    compute_metrics = ComputeMetrics,

)

T.train()
```

The line `print(RawData)` outputs

```
DatasetDict({
    train: Dataset({
        features: ['Label', 'Title', 'Text'],
        num_rows: 350
    })
    test: Dataset({
        features: ['Label', 'Title', 'Text'],
        num_rows: 141
    })
})
```

I thought I had replicated the code in the example but my code returns an error.

I am receiving the following error when I try to train the model:

```
You're using a DistilBertTokenizerFast tokenizer. Please note that with a fast tokenizer, using the `__call__` method is faster than using a method to encode the text followed by a call to the `pad` method to get a padded encoding.

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-27-3f5976e978e2> in <cell line: 28>()
     26 )
     27 
---> 28 Trainer.train()

3 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/trainer.py in train(self, resume_from_checkpoint, trial, ignore_keys_for_eval, **kwargs)
   1553                 hf_hub_utils.enable_progress_bars()
   1554         else:
-> 1555             return inner_training_loop(
   1556                 args=args,
   1557                 resume_from_checkpoint=resume_from_checkpoint,

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/trainer.py in _inner_training_loop(self, batch_size, args, resume_from_checkpoint, trial, ignore_keys_for_eval)
   1858 
   1859                 with self.accelerator.accumulate(model):
-> 1860                     tr_loss_step = self.training_step(model, inputs)
   1861 
   1862                 if (

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/trainer.py in training_step(self, model, inputs)
   2723 
   2724         with self.compute_loss_context_manager():
-> 2725             loss = self.compute_loss(model, inputs)
   2726 
   2727         if self.args.n_gpu > 1:

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/trainer.py in compute_loss(self, model, inputs, return_outputs)
   2763         else:
   2764             if isinstance(outputs, dict) and "loss" not in outputs:
-> 2765                 raise ValueError(
   2766                     "The model did not return a loss from the inputs, only the following keys: "
   2767                     f"{','.join(outputs.keys())}. For reference, the inputs it received are {','.join(inputs.keys())}."

ValueError: The model did not return a loss from the inputs, only the following keys: logits. For reference, the inputs it received are input_ids,attention_mask.
```

How does my code differ from the example? As far as I can tell they only use different variable names and a different data set.

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this?

Comment: How do you define the target of the input? (Because thats what missing). How does a training sample actually look like?

Comment: This is the entire code... Its all that was in the example as well. I'm not certain what I'm missing...

Comment: Can you print the first examples from your train dataset? Try this: `next(iter(RawDataset["Train"]))`

Comment: `dataset['train'].features` might be sufficient too

Answer (score 0):

**Assure that your `"labels"` column in your data is lower-cased** instead of `"Labels"`.
Rename them in your csv. files

---

Reason roughly there is this code:

```py
 if self.label_smoother is not None and "labels" in inputs:
            labels = inputs.pop("labels")
        else:
            labels = None
            ...
            if isinstance(outputs, dict) and "loss" not in outputs:
                raise ValueError( "The model did not return a loss from the inputs, only the following keys: "...)
```

---

More complicated is use `Features` and `ClassLabels` to relabel your columns. See [here](https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/v2.16.1/about_dataset_features) and [here](https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/v2.16.1/loading#specify-features) for examples.

Disclaimer I did not test the below code, and would recommend to just use lower-case column headings by default.

```py
features = Features({'Text': Value('string'), 'Label': ClassLabel(names=["Human", "AI"])})

dataset = load_dataset('csv', data_files=data_files = {"train": "Dataset Train.csv", "test": "Dataset Test.csv"}, 
            column_names=['Text', 'Label'], features=features)
```